# telebot, python, Ответы на вопросы

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Как сделать так, чтобы бот запоминал ответы на вопросы, и в последствии отправлял сообщение, которое конструировал бы из всех ответов?

Comment: а что сложного?

Comment: Не знаю как это реализовать. Бот задает вопросы, и пользователь отвечает через кнопки на них. Нужно чтобы бот запоминал ответы, которые пишет пользователь, чтобы потом отправить сообщение, в котором будут содержаться ответы пользователя.

Comment: тут все достаточно примитивно - если писать это функциональным стилем, то можно их просто пихать в самый обычный список

Comment: нужно будет использовать состояния, ответил на 1 вопрос - сотояние "1 ответ верный", задается вротой вопрос - ответил правильно - состояние "2 ответ верный" и тд

Comment: https://groosha.gitbook.io/telegram-bot-lessons/chapter1 - это я нашел при первом поиске в гугле